# using vuejs to append all the items in an array into a div using v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vuejs method that appends data on a screen. My issue is, I want to append all of the items found in the array to the screen using v-for instead of just one that is filtered by an index?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    chocs:[{"title":'a man tale'}, {"title":'a boy tale'},{"title":'a mermaid tale'},{"title":'a dog tale'}]  
  }),
  methods: {
    handleTileClick: function(){

      $("#fox").append(`<div id="popover-dialog">data here: ${this.chocs.title}</div>`
      );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <button v-on:click="handleTileClick()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="fox" v-for="choc in chocs"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 name: "App",
 data: () => ({
    showList: false,
    chocs: [
      { title: "a man tale" },
      { title: "a boy tale" },
      { title: "a mermaid tale" },
      { title: "a dog tale" },
    ],
  }),
 methods: {
    handleTileClick: function () {
      this.showList = true;
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <button v-on:click="handleTileClick">Click Me</button>
  <div id="fox" v-if="showList">
   <div id="list-item" v-for="(choc, index) in chocs" :key="index">{{ choc.title }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Your right mate, if you wanna add something...feel free to edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can first hide the elements and show them after click on the `click Me` button:

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

```
<div id="fox" v-if="isShowing">
  <div id="popover-dialog" v-for="choc in chocs" :key="choc.title">
    data here: {{ choc.title }}
  </div>
</div>
```

`data` and `methods` as:

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    isShowing: false,
    chocs: [
      { title: "a man tale" },
      { title: "a boy tale" },
      { title: "a mermaid tale" },
      { title: "a dog tale" },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    handleTileClick: function () {
      this.isShowing = true;
    },
  },
};
```